# publishing a database project doesn't create the database in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Can't seem to figure out how to publish a dbproject to Azure and have Azure create the DB.
I thought I could just publish to Azure and it would automatically create the DB for me in the Portal. Am I missing something? Do I need to create a dacpac or something and then use that?
How does this work without having to go into the portal first and create the db then import it into VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, if using Entity Frameworks 'auto create DB functionality' you have to create the web site from Azure first and create the database 'server' instance. EF can create a DB in a SQL instance but can't create an instance of SQL.

From the portal create a new web site, you must select the 'custom' option, this is where you choose\setup a database for the web site. Once you do this you can export your publish profile, import into VS and set db connection in the publish wizard.

Comment: Hi Mikee, I'm not using EF, just ADO.Net. So what your saying is before I can publish a DB to Azure, I have to create it in the Azure portal first?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong, I was thinking web site with a DB, not a database project. I just had a fit getting my web site to create my db upon publish so that is what was on my mind.

With that being said you may have the same problem with a DB Project, it needs an instance of SQL Azure to be around before it can create the database inside.

Comment: well actually you aren't incorrect. I have a ASP.Net MVC 4 app. The .sqlproj was created to support the ASP application. So yes it is a web site with a DB. But when pushing it to Azure, it seems like I have to recreate it in Azure before I can publish? I do have a SQL Database set up in Azure (ex. someolddb), so I can obtain all the correct connection info (username/password/servername/etc) but now I want to create a new db (.sqlproj) (ex. somenewdb) in VS and publish that to Azure. Do I still have to create a new DB in Azure before I publish?

Comment: I'm not up on .sqlproj types and I don't think ADO will auto create DBs like Entity Framework does. So you will probably have to create it manually or look into the VS publish stuff. Go to your web project properties 'Package/Publish SQL' tab, which has changed in VS2013, more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576376)